# What is the maximum number of nested functions in PIC16F628A?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c

What is the maximum number of nested functions in [PIC16F628A](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40044E.pdf)?

ex. [NEW CODE, should be more explanatory]

```
int main(){
    function1();
}

void function1(){
    function2();
}

void function2(){
    function3();
}

void function3(){
    function4();
}
// And so on 
void functionX-1(){
    functionX();
}
```

ex. [OLD CODE, not so clear for the question]

```
int main(){
     function1(); //PIC goes in function 1         
      function2(); //Function 2 is inside function1, PIC goes in function 2
       function3(); //Function 3 is inside function2,  PIC goes in function 3
                    //...
         functionX(); //Function X is inside functionX-1 
                      //^^^PIC goes in function X where it ends executing the code 
                    //a lot of } here
    }
```

Does *main()* count as function?
In the datasheet it says *8-level deep hardware stack*. Does that mean X=8? If not, then X=?

Comment: You can't nest functions like this in standard C.

Comment: @RogerRowland Please check the code, I have edited it.

Comment: Remember to reserve a stack level (or more) for interrupts!

Comment: You're not nesting more than 2 functions there, main() and function*().

Comment: The difference between those codes is not that the first is clearer. The working of these codes is fundamentally different!

Comment: Why are people still using stone age MCUs with limited stack depth? Maybe upgrade to a CPU core from 1980 or later...

Comment: I share @Lundin's sentiments. C & PIC 8 bit cores were never a happy marriage. As to how deep you can stack - further to Majenko's answer, the PIC C compiler may be smart enough to substitute function calls with jumps where a given function is only called from one place. Do yourself a favour and choose a more modern microcontroller with debug capability.  XMC2GO or a Nucleo -  with Arduino something with Arduino support.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The datasheet says you have a 8 level deep hardware stack.

That means you can push the registers onto the stack no more than 8 times before the oldest one drops off the end.

Assuming main() is called as a function (which is dependent on how crt0 is written for your compiler), that takes one slot, that leaves you with 7 slots. Not that, under normal circumstances, you really care if that one drops off the end or not, since you shouldn't be returning from main().

One slot should be reserved for interrupts, so you get 6 slots.

Don't forget that library functions, like tan(), sprintf(), atoi(), etc are all functions as well, so using anything like that will use a slot. That leaves 5 slots.

There's always a chance that a library function may call another function, so save at least one for that - that leaves 4 slots available.

So really you don't want to be nesting more than 3 or 4 levels deep to be on the safe side.  So keep your program nice and flat and you will be OK.

Making smaller utility functions "inline" will decrease your stack usage (and the compiler may do that for you automatically sometimes), but will increase your flash usage.

Comment: Main doesn't take up a slot whether it is called or jumped to, as long as you never try to return from main.  On this PIC, pushing a address onto the stack simply causes the oldest to be lost.  There is no harm in the return address of main being lost if you don't ever use it.

Comment: I already mentioned the dropping off in paragraph 2. I have enhanced paragraph 3 to highlight not caring about main's slot.

Comment: Right, sorry, I read that last part too quickly.